# How to Mark Pixels in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an image and am trying to mark pixels that are green as 0 and everything not green as 1. However since pixels are in the format (x,y) I'm not sure how to go about it. So far I have loaded the image and extracted the green color channel, assuming that it is in RGB format, so something like (0,255,0)

Here's what I have so far:

```
% read in the image and display to make sure its loading correctly
    I = imread('Sample.tif');
    imshow(I)
    % extract green color channel
    green = I(:,:,2);
    % Extract all green pixels as an array? Then mark them as 0?

    % Display resulting image 
    imshow(I)
```

Any recommendations or resources here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't use a single channel to separate colours, for reasons that will become obvious if you consider what value pure white will have in R, G and B.  Colour segmentation is more normally done not in RGB but in another colourspace like HSV.

Comment: I see, so I have converted to HSV colorspace before using `rgb2hsv()` but the question still is, what operation do I need to perform on the value channel to mark the pixels?

Comment: What does the final image should look like? It sounds like you want to create a new image with (originally) green pixel as 0 and 1 otherwise. In this manner you'll get a black-and-white picture.

Comment: Correct, it should be a black and white image. I will be adding noise to it after I have created the new image with marked pixels.

Comment: Ok, I have converted the image to hsv colorspace. I know I will need to mark the pixels in the hue channel since I can define green in there somehow. Is there a range of hues that green can be?

Comment: And furthermore, now that I'm working in hsv space, I still don't know if there is syntax that can do something like this:
`// if( <valueOfPixels> == greenHueValue) { // markPixels as zero} else { //markPixels as one}`

Clearly this is rough pseudocode, but I expect the idea is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of exactly what you are after with your question, but the code below may help you in achieving the result. If you leave a comment, I can perhaps improve the answer.

0) Read in an image in RGB format.

First option: Separate out green and other components (each plotted separately), and make a final plot of all non-green components set to 1. Note: this results in a fully black image as all components have some amount of green.

Second option: Separate the image into either Red, Green or Blue based on the maximum contribution. The last plot shows the conversion to black and white. Note: The algorithm is not vectorized so this would be slow if processing large/many images.

```
I = imread('autumn.tif');

IG = I; IG(:,:,[1 3]) = 0; % Green only
INoG = I-IG; 
INoG1 = INoG; INoG1(abs(INoG1) > 0) = 1; 
              % Possibly what you want?


% Display resulting images
subplot(4,2,1)
imshow(I)
title('Original');

subplot(4,2,2)
imshow(INoG)
title('No Green');

subplot(4,2,3)
imshow(IG)
title('Only Green');

subplot(4,2,4)
imshow(INoG1)
title('No Green (all 1?)');
% Note: There is a bit of each color in every pixel...
%       => Potential solution: Use major contributor

% Not vectorized => Slow for large images
IRGB = I*0;
for i = 1:size(I,1)
for j = 1:size(I,2)
    [~,k] = max(I(i,j,:));
    if (size(k) > 1)
        k = k(1);
    end

    IRGB(i,j,k) = 255;
end
end

IRGBG = IRGB; IRGBG(:,:,[1 3]) = 0; % Green only
IRGBNoG = IRGB-IRGBG; 
BandWNoG = IRGBG(:,:,2); % Possibly what you want?

% Display resulting images
subplot(4,2,5)
imshow(IRGB);
title('RGB - Original');

subplot(4,2,6)
imshow(IRGBNoG);
title('RGB - No Green');

subplot(4,2,7)
imshow(IRGBG);
title('RGB - Only Green');

subplot(4,2,8)
imshow(BandWNoG)
title('Black and White - No Green');
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking to do. I partially got what you have here now. Anyways, the subplots are excellent to see what is happening at each processing step, I can add my noise and continue, thanks @PZwan